# Sourcemaps inaccurate (Vue + webpack + sentry)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, source-maps, sentry

I'm trying to generate correct sourcemaps for my project written in vue2 so I could later use them in sentry. However right now when I upload them to Sentry, everything seems to be working fine apart from Sentry complaining that it cannot match the location in the source map.  Sourcemap Validator also thinks so: 
http://sourcemaps.io/report/1578938920829_http%3A%2F%2F7ec94d64.ngrok.io%2FSideMenuAnalytics.40e8f1227591b28bea7d.js

It looks that sourcemap mappings are off by X characters. Have you seen something like that and could give me a hint how to solve it? Or can someone share webpack config which is producing correct sourcemaps?

PS. I've found this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8302#issuecomment-521779175 but I'm not sure if it's actually related to my problem.

source file (.js):

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[35],{485:function(t,e,i){var n=i(604);"string"==typeof n&&(n=[[t.i,n,""]]),n.locals&&(t.exports=n.locals);(0,i(8).default)("8850203c",n,!0,{})},603:function(t,e,i){"use strict";var n=i(485);i.n(n).a},604:function(t,e,i){(e=i(7)(!1)).push([t.i,".sidebar-menu__item{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;margin-bottom:22px;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column}.sidebar-menu__tab{width:100%;border-left:4px solid transparent;padding-left:16px;color:#6d7688;display:inline-block;font-weight:500;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:middle;word-break:break-word}.sidebar-menu__tab--active{border-left:4px solid #1593ff;color:#1a2a4a;font-weight:500}.sidebar-menu__activetab{color:#0079e1}@media(max-width: 768px){.sidebar-menu{-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row}}.sidebar-submenu{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;width:100%;padding-left:20px}.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-menu__item{margin-bottom:1em}",""]),t.exports=e},605:function(t,e,i){var n=i(776);"string"==typeof n&&(n=[[t.i,n,""]]),n.locals&&(t.exports=n.locals);(0,i(8).default)("737a94e4",n,!0,{})},639:function(t,e,i){"use strict";i(22),i(94),i(23);var n={name:"SideMenu",components:{BaseSelect:i(51).r},props:["items","exactlyMatchRoute"],data:function(){return{options:[],menuItem:this.$route.name}},watch:{menuItem:function(t){this.$router.push({name:t}),this.menuItem=t}},methods:{flatten:function(t){var e=this;return t.reduce((function(t,i){return t.push({value:i.name,text:i.i18n}),i.items&&(t=t.concat(e.flatten(i.items))),t}),[])}},created:function(){this.options=this.flatten(this.items)}},a=(i(603),i(1)),o=Object(a.a)(n,(function(){var t=this,e=t.$createElement,i=t._self._c||e;return i("div",[i("ul",{staticClass:"sidebar-menu hidden-xs"},t._l(t.items,(function(e){return i("li",{key:e.name},[i("div",{staticClass:"sidebar-menu__item"},[i("router-link",{staticClass:"sidebar-menu__tab",attrs:{"active-class":"sidebar-menu__tab--active",to:{name:e.name},tag:"a",exact:t.exactlyMatchRoute}},[t._v(t._s(e.i18n))]),e.items?i("ul",{staticClass:"sidebar-submenu"},t._l(e.items,(function(e){return i("li",{key:e.name},[i("router-link",{staticClass:"sidebar-menu__tab",attrs:{"active-class":"sidebar-menu__tab--active",to:{name:e.name},tag:"a",exact:!0}},[t._v(t._s(e.i18n))])],1)})),0):t._e()],1)])})),0),i("BaseSelect",{attrs:{classes:"large visible-xs-block",options:t.options},model:{value:t.menuItem,callback:function(e){t.menuItem=e},expression:"menuItem"}})],1)}),[],!1,null,null,null);e.a=o.exports},775:function(t,e,i){"use strict";var n=i(605);i.n(n).a},776:function(t,e,i){(e=i(7)(!1)).push([t.i,".partner-settings__contact{margin-bottom:20px}.partner-settings__title{margin-bottom:20px}.settings__row{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row;margin-bottom:20px}.settings__row button:first-child{margin-right:25px}.settings__column{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column;width:50%;padding-right:20px}.partner-settings__label{font-weight:500}",""]),t.exports=e},858:function(t,e,i){"use strict";i.r(e);var n={components:{SideMenu:i(639).a},data:function(){return{items:[{name:"general-performance",i18n:this.$t("pPartner general performance")},{name:"campaigns-performance",i18n:this.$t("pPartner campaigns performance")},{i18n:this.$t("jsPartner_analytics overview bookings"),name:"bookings-all",items:[{name:"bookings-all",i18n:this.$t("jsPartner_analytics overview all bookings")},{name:"bookings-conducted",i18n:this.$t("jsPartner_analytics overview conducted bookings")}]}]}}},a=(i(775),i(1)),o=Object(a.a)(n,(function(){var t=this.$createElement;return(this._self._c||t)("SideMenu",{attrs:{items:this.items,exactlyMatchRoute:!1}})}),[],!1,null,null,null);e.default=o.exports}}]);
# sourceMappingURL=SideMenuAnalytics.40e8f1227591b28bea7d.js.map
```

sourcemap file (.js.map):

```
{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue?b476","webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue?f4a6","webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue?ddfe","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue?6589","webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue?6646","webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue?82ff","webpack:///src/components/SideMenu.vue","webpack:///./src/components/SideMenu.vue","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue?eb0c","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue?0508","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue?258b","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue?a09f","webpack:///src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue","webpack:///./src/pages/analytics/SideMenuAnalytics.vue"],"names":["content","module","i","locals","exports","add","default","___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___","push","component","_vm","this","_h","$createElement","_c","_self","staticClass","_l","tab","key","name","attrs","exactlyMatchRoute","_v","_s","i18n","t","_e","options","model","value","callback","$$v","menuItem","expression","items"],"mappings":"8EAGA,IAAIA,EAAU,EAAQ,KACA,iBAAZA,IAAsBA,EAAU,CAAC,CAACC,EAAOC,EAAIF,EAAS,MAC7DA,EAAQG,SAAQF,EAAOG,QAAUJ,EAAQG,SAG/BE,EADH,EAAQ,GAA+DC,SAChE,WAAYN,GAAS,EAAM,K,iCCR5C,oBAA2b,G,qBCE3bI,EADkC,EAAQ,EAChCG,EAA4B,IAE9BC,KAAK,CAACP,EAAOC,EAAI,wwBAAywB,KAElyBD,EAAOG,QAAUA,G,oBCHjB,IAAIJ,EAAU,EAAQ,KACA,iBAAZA,IAAsBA,EAAU,CAAC,CAACC,EAAOC,EAAIF,EAAS,MAC7DA,EAAQG,SAAQF,EAAOG,QAAUJ,EAAQG,SAG/BE,EADH,EAAQ,GAAkEC,SACnE,WAAYN,GAAS,EAAM,K,mDCR5C,ICAgM,ECkChM,CACE,KAAF,WACE,WAAF,CACI,W,MAAJ,GAEE,MAAF,8BACE,KAAF,WACI,MAAJ,CACM,QAAN,GACM,SAAN,mBAGE,MAAF,CACI,SAAJ,YACM,KAAN,cAAQ,KAAR,IACM,KAAN,aAGE,QAAF,CACI,QAAJ,YAAM,IAAN,OACM,OAAN,wBAKQ,OAJA,EAAR,MAAU,MAAV,OAAU,KAAV,SACA,UACU,EAAV,8BAEA,IACA,MAGE,QAAF,WACI,KAAJ,mC,gBCxDIS,EAAY,YACd,GHTW,WAAa,IAAIC,EAAIC,KAASC,EAAGF,EAAIG,eAAmBC,EAAGJ,EAAIK,MAAMD,IAAIF,EAAG,OAAOE,EAAG,MAAM,CAACA,EAAG,KAAK,CAACE,YAAY,0BAA0BN,EAAIO,GAAIP,EAAS,OAAE,SAASQ,GAAK,OAAOJ,EAAG,KAAK,CAACK,IAAID,EAAIE,MAAM,CAACN,EAAG,MAAM,CAACE,YAAY,sBAAsB,CAACF,EAAG,cAAc,CAACE,YAAY,oBAAoBK,MAAM,CAAC,eAAe,4BAA4B,GAAK,CAAED,KAAMF,EAAIE,MAAM,IAAM,IAAI,MAAQV,EAAIY,oBAAoB,CAACZ,EAAIa,GAAGb,EAAIc,GAAGN,EAAIO,SAAUP,EAAS,MAAEJ,EAAG,KAAK,CAACE,YAAY,mBAAmBN,EAAIO,GAAIC,EAAS,OAAE,SAASQ,GAAG,OAAOZ,EAAG,KAAK,CAACK,IAAIO,EAAEN,MAAM,CAACN,EAAG,cAAc,CAACE,YAAY,oBAAoBK,MAAM,CAAC,eAAe,4BAA4B,GAAK,CAAED,KAAMM,EAAEN,MAAM,IAAM,IAAI,OAAQ,IAAO,CAACV,EAAIa,GAAGb,EAAIc,GAAGE,EAAED,UAAU,MAAK,GAAGf,EAAIiB,MAAM,QAAO,GAAGb,EAAG,aAAa,CAACO,MAAM,CAAC,QAAU,yBAAyB,QAAUX,EAAIkB,SAASC,MAAM,CAACC,MAAOpB,EAAY,SAAEqB,SAAS,SAAUC,GAAMtB,EAAIuB,SAASD,GAAKE,WAAW,eAAe,KAC75B,IGWpB,EACA,KACA,KACA,MAIa,IAAAzB,E,0CCnBf,oBAAsd,G,qBCEtdL,EADkC,EAAQ,EAChCG,EAA4B,IAE9BC,KAAK,CAACP,EAAOC,EAAI,0eAA2e,KAEpgBD,EAAOG,QAAUA,G,wCCNjB,ICA+M,ECO/M,CACE,WAAF,CAAI,S,OAAJ,GACE,KAFF,WAGI,MAAJ,CACM,MAAN,CACA,CAAQ,KAAR,sBAAQ,KAAR,yCACA,CAAQ,KAAR,wBAAQ,KAAR,2CACA,CACQ,KAAR,iDACQ,KAAR,eACQ,MAAR,CACA,CAAU,KAAV,eAAU,KAAV,sDACA,CAAU,KAAV,qBAAU,KAAV,kE,gBCXIK,EAAY,YACd,GHTW,WAAa,IAAiBG,EAATD,KAAgBE,eAAuC,OAAvDF,KAA0CI,MAAMD,IAAIF,GAAa,WAAW,CAACS,MAAM,CAAC,MAApFV,KAAgGwB,MAAM,mBAAoB,OACtI,IGWpB,EACA,KACA,KACA,MAIa,UAAA1B,E","file":"SideMenuAnalytics.40e8f1227591b28bea7d.js","sourcesContent":["// style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag\n\n// load the styles\nvar content = require(\"!!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\");\nif(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];\nif(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;\n// add the styles to the DOM\nvar add = require(\"!../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js\").default\nvar update = add(\"8850203c\", content, true, {});","import mod from \"-!../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"; export default mod; export * from \"-!../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"","// Imports\nvar ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = require(\"../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js\");\nexports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);\n// Module\nexports.push([module.id, \".sidebar-menu__item{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;align-items:center;margin-bottom:22px;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column}.sidebar-menu__tab{width:100%;border-left:4px solid transparent;padding-left:16px;color:#6d7688;display:inline-block;font-weight:500;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:middle;word-break:break-word}.sidebar-menu__tab--active{border-left:4px solid #1593ff;color:#1a2a4a;font-weight:500}.sidebar-menu__activetab{color:#0079e1}@media(max-width: 768px){.sidebar-menu{-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row}}.sidebar-submenu{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;width:100%;padding-left:20px}.sidebar-submenu .sidebar-menu__item{margin-bottom:1em}\", \"\"]);\n// Exports\nmodule.exports = exports;\n","// style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag\n\n// load the styles\nvar content = require(\"!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\");\nif(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];\nif(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;\n// add the styles to the DOM\nvar add = require(\"!../../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js\").default\nvar update = add(\"737a94e4\", content, true, {});","var render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',[_c('ul',{staticClass:\"sidebar-menu hidden-xs\"},_vm._l((_vm.items),function(tab){return _c('li',{key:tab.name},[_c('div',{staticClass:\"sidebar-menu__item\"},[_c('router-link',{staticClass:\"sidebar-menu__tab\",attrs:{\"active-class\":\"sidebar-menu__tab--active\",\"to\":{ name: tab.name},\"tag\":\"a\",\"exact\":_vm.exactlyMatchRoute}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(tab.i18n))]),(tab.items)?_c('ul',{staticClass:\"sidebar-submenu\"},_vm._l((tab.items),function(t){return _c('li',{key:t.name},[_c('router-link',{staticClass:\"sidebar-menu__tab\",attrs:{\"active-class\":\"sidebar-menu__tab--active\",\"to\":{ name: t.name},\"tag\":\"a\",\"exact\":true}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(t.i18n))])],1)}),0):_vm._e()],1)])}),0),_c('BaseSelect',{attrs:{\"classes\":\"large visible-xs-block\",\"options\":_vm.options},model:{value:(_vm.menuItem),callback:function ($$v) {_vm.menuItem=$$v},expression:\"menuItem\"}})],1)}\nvar staticRenderFns = []\n\nexport { render, staticRenderFns }","import mod from \"-!../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"; export default mod; export * from \"-!../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"","<template>\n    <div>\n        <ul class=\"sidebar-menu hidden-xs\">\n            <li :key=\"tab.name\" v-for=\"tab in items\">\n                <div class=\"sidebar-menu__item\">\n                    <router-link\n                        active-class=\"sidebar-menu__tab--active\"\n                        class=\"sidebar-menu__tab\"\n                        :to=\"{ name: tab.name}\"\n                        tag=\"a\"\n                        :exact=\"exactlyMatchRoute\"\n                    >{{tab.i18n}}</router-link>\n                    <!-- second level navigation (this section displays children nested underneath the main element -->\n                    <ul class=\"sidebar-submenu\" v-if=\"tab.items\">\n                        <li :key=\"t.name\" v-for=\"t in tab.items\">\n                            <router-link\n                                active-class=\"sidebar-menu__tab--active\"\n                                class=\"sidebar-menu__tab\"\n                                :to=\"{ name: t.name}\"\n                                tag=\"a\"\n                                :exact=\"true\"\n                            >{{t.i18n}}</router-link>\n                        </li>\n                    </ul>\n                </div>\n            </li>\n        </ul>\n        <BaseSelect classes=\"large visible-xs-block\" :options=\"options\" v-model=\"menuItem\" />\n    </div>\n</template>\n\n<script>\nimport { BaseSelect } from 'Components/base/index';\n\nexport default {\n    name: 'SideMenu',\n    components: {\n        BaseSelect\n    },\n    props: ['items', 'exactlyMatchRoute'],\n    data: function () {\n        return {\n            options: [],\n            menuItem: this.$route.name\n        }\n    },\n    watch: {\n        menuItem: function (name) {\n            this.$router.push({ name });\n            this.menuItem = name;\n        }\n    },\n    methods: {\n        flatten: function (array) {\n            return array.reduce((acc, value) => {\n                acc.push({ value: value.name, text: value.i18n });\n                if (value.items) {\n                    acc = acc.concat(this.flatten(value.items));\n                }\n                return acc;\n            }, []);\n        }\n    },\n    created: function () {\n        this.options = this.flatten(this.items)\n    }\n};\n</script>\n\n<style lang=\"scss\">\n@import \"~@getyourguide/design-system/colors/colors\";\n@import \"~@getyourguide/design-system/spacing/breakpoints\";\n\n$border-width: 4px;\n$indent: 16px;\n\n.sidebar-menu {\n    &__item {\n        display: flex;\n        align-items: center;\n        margin-bottom: 22px;\n        flex-direction: column;\n    }\n\n    &__tab {\n        width: 100%;\n        border-left: $border-width solid transparent;\n        padding-left: $indent;\n        color: $ui-slate;\n        display: inline-block;\n        font-weight: 500;\n        text-decoration: none;\n        vertical-align: middle;\n        word-break: break-word;\n\n        &--active {\n            border-left: $border-width solid #1593ff;\n            color: #1a2a4a;\n            font-weight: 500;\n        }\n    }\n\n    &__activetab {\n        color: $cta-active;\n    }\n\n    @media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {\n        flex-direction: row;\n    }\n}\n\n.sidebar-submenu {\n    margin-top: $border-width + $indent;\n    margin-bottom: $border-width + $indent;\n    width: 100%;\n    padding-left: $border-width + $indent;\n\n    // Reset margin in submenu items\n    .sidebar-menu__item {\n        margin-bottom: 1em;\n    }\n}\n</style>\n","import { render, staticRenderFns } from \"./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=template&id=39191e03&\"\nimport script from \"./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"\nexport * from \"./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"\nimport style0 from \"./SideMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"\n\n\n/* normalize component */\nimport normalizer from \"!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js\"\nvar component = normalizer(\n  script,\n  render,\n  staticRenderFns,\n  false,\n  null,\n  null,\n  null\n  \n)\n\nexport default component.exports","import mod from \"-!../../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"; export default mod; export * from \"-!../../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-1!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-2!../../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--2-oneOf-0-3!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"","// Imports\nvar ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = require(\"../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js\");\nexports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);\n// Module\nexports.push([module.id, \".partner-settings__contact{margin-bottom:20px}.partner-settings__title{margin-bottom:20px}.settings__row{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row;margin-bottom:20px}.settings__row button:first-child{margin-right:25px}.settings__column{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column;width:50%;padding-right:20px}.partner-settings__label{font-weight:500}\", \"\"]);\n// Exports\nmodule.exports = exports;\n","var render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('SideMenu',{attrs:{\"items\":_vm.items,\"exactlyMatchRoute\":false}})}\nvar staticRenderFns = []\n\nexport { render, staticRenderFns }","import mod from \"-!../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--1!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"; export default mod; export * from \"-!../../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--1!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"","<template>\n    <SideMenu :items=\"items\" :exactlyMatchRoute=\"false\"/>\n</template>\n\n<script>\nimport SideMenu from '../../components/SideMenu.vue';\n\nexport default {\n    components: { SideMenu },\n    data() {\n        return {\n            items: [\n                { name: 'general-performance', i18n: this.$t('pPartner general performance') },\n                { name: 'campaigns-performance', i18n: this.$t('pPartner campaigns performance') },\n                {\n                    i18n: this.$t('jsPartner_analytics overview bookings'),\n                    name: 'bookings-all',\n                    items: [\n                        {name: 'bookings-all', i18n: this.$t('jsPartner_analytics overview all bookings')},\n                        {name: 'bookings-conducted', i18n: this.$t('jsPartner_analytics overview conducted bookings')},\n                    ]\n                }\n            ]\n        };\n    }\n};\n</script>\n\n<style lang=\"scss\">\n// TODO: title, columns, rows definitions should not\n// live here. All those definitions should be moved into\n// its own components.\n\n.partner-settings__contact {\n    margin-bottom: 20px;\n}\n\n.partner-settings__title {\n    margin-bottom: 20px;\n}\n\n.settings__row {\n    display: flex;\n    flex-direction: row;\n    margin-bottom: 20px;\n\n    button {\n        &:first-child {\n            margin-right: 25px;\n        }\n    }\n}\n\n.settings__column {\n    display: flex;\n    flex-direction: column;\n    width: 50%;\n    padding-right: 20px;\n}\n\n.partner-settings__label {\n    font-weight: 500;\n}\n</style>\n","import { render, staticRenderFns } from \"./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=template&id=6982eed3&\"\nimport script from \"./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"\nexport * from \"./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"\nimport style0 from \"./SideMenuAnalytics.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&\"\n\n\n/* normalize component */\nimport normalizer from \"!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js\"\nvar component = normalizer(\n  script,\n  render,\n  staticRenderFns,\n  false,\n  null,\n  null,\n  null\n  \n)\n\nexport default component.exports"],"sourceRoot":""}
```

webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require("friendly-errors-webpack-plugin");
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require("moment-locales-webpack-plugin");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const state = require("../state");

const { isProd } = state;

module.exports = {
  mode: isProd ? "production" : "development",
  devtool: isProd ? "source-map" : "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./public/assets/compiled"),
    publicPath: "/assets/compiled/",
    filename: "[name].[hash].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Public: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./public"),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/components/"),
      Mixins: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/mixins/"),
      Store: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/store/"),
      Util: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/util/"),
      Pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/pages/"),
      Styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "./src/styles/")
    }
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/, // avoid webpack shimming process
    // noParse: /^(vue|vue-router|vuex|vuex-router-sync)$/,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
        options: {
          compilerOptions: {
            preserveWhitespace: false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        // In order to enable es6 module for SSR render it's necessary to tell babel
        // that it should process module files.
        // Reference: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3485
        // We should only use include || exclude
        exclude: function(modulePath) {
          return (
            /node_modules/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules\/@getyourguide\/design-system/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules\/@getyourguide\/event-logger/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules\/@sentry\/browser/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules\/v-tooltip/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules\/vue-18n/.test(modulePath)
          );
        },
        options: {
          presets: [
            [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                debug: false,
                useBuiltIns: "usage",
                corejs: 3,
                targets: {
                  ie: "11"
                },
                modules: 'auto' // Needed for tree shaking to work.
              }
            ]
          ],
          plugins: [
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            use: [
              "vue-style-loader",
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  sourceMap: false
                }
              },
              {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: false,
                  plugins: [
                    require("autoprefixer")({
                      grid: true,
                      flexbox: true
                    })
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                  implementation: require("sass"),
                  sourceMap: false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 300000,
    hints: isProd ? "warning" : false
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "common.[hash].css"
    }),
    ...(isProd ? [] : [new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()]),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    //     generateStatsFile: true,
    //     openAnalyzer: true
    // }),

    // To strip all locales except “en”
    new MomentLocalesPlugin()
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: isProd
      ? [
          new TerserPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
          })
        ]
      : []
  }
};
```